# install jupyter notebook with dnf

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am reporting a problem installing jupyter notebook on a Fedora 28 system using dnf install notebook or dnf install jupyter-notebook. The installed code crashes when I run *jupyter notebook* , and the traceback shows permission problems.

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 710, in _default_cookie_secret
with io.open(self.cookie_secret_file, 'rb') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/run/user/1000/jupyter/notebook_cookie_secret'
```

I suspect a configuration problem since /run/user/1000 is owned by root.
The default paths set are:
    *jupyter --paths*

```
config:
    /home/olin/.jupyter
    /usr/etc/jupyter
    /usr/local/etc/jupyter
    /etc/jupyter

data:
    /home/olin/.local/share/jupyter
    /usr/local/share/jupyter
    /usr/share/jupyter

runtime:
    /run/user/1000/jupyter
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, simple answer.
*chmod a+r /run/user/1000/jupyter* and
*chmod a+r /run/user/1000/jupyter/notebook_cookie_secret*
fixes the problem.
This needs to be added to the documentation...